# Forward fill n missing periods of a list with the average of the m following occurrences - python

Tags: python, list, fillna

In python I would like to forward fill n missing periods of a list (or pd.series) with the average of the m following occurrences :

example with n = 2 and m = 3

```
#input:
lst = [None,None,1,2,3, None,None,4, 5, 6] #2 is average of 1,2,3 and 5 of 4,5,6

#do stuff

#expected output: 
lst = [2,2,1,2,3,5,5,4,5, 6]
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the first element `2`? Is it `(None + 1 + 3)/3`? `(1 + 3)/2`? If the second, why is the first `5` not `4.5`?

Comment: @handlist thank you for pointing it out. Indeed it should have been 1,2, 3 in the first series .  I have corrected my example (if it is still possible to edit)

Comment: Also I found a way with pandas by grouping by , averaging and padding missing values.